# Gogland: debugging has redundant parameter '--'

Tags: debugging, go, goland

'Program arguments' is empty as below,

[image]

but when I start debugging, there is a '--' parameter at end.

Where does the parameter come from, and how can I avoid it?

[image]

When I add some debug parameters, the '--' is still there , just between program name and the real parameters. It will break the debugging, because program doesn't know how to interpret it.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is automatically added by the IDE and its there to separate the parameter sent to delve from the parameters sent to the application. In case you don't have any parameters then, as you say, it's redundant but it's not harmful / shouldn't bother you. Is there any problem that you currently have with the IDE?

Edit: This was fixed in the newer EAPs starting from EAP 8.

Comment: Yes there is a problem. When I add some debug parameters, the '--' is still there , just between program name and the real parameters. It will break the debugging, because program doesn't know how to interpret it.

Comment: That problem was an issue in delve, you can install either the nightly plugin or switch the debugging backend to native via Preferences | Building, Debugging and Deployment | Debugger | Delve. However this might result in some apps not being debuggable.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  By changing backend to 'native', I can debug now, though it crashes sometimes.  By the way, what is the nightly plugin, I'm using Gogland IDE.

Comment: It's basically the core of Gogland but updated every night (which also implies that from time to time there might be bugs). Using the nightly backend you should be able to use the default backend again. You can read here (at the end of the article) on how to use it in the IDE: https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2017/05/12/gogland-eap-8-is-available/ Hope it helps.

Also let me know if I need to edit my answer but technically there's no way to get rid of those -- as a user which makes the answer correct.